# Can I get data from my application to use it in default android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, sharedpreferences

I have an application in which I can select an *On* or *Off* value so:

- When I select *On* and open the keyboard dialer, the dialer gets the first part of a number from my application.
- When I select *Off*, the dialer acts normally.

Can anyone help me to do this please?

Comment: You'll have to explain the flow: does a user open your app, set his preference, go to the dialer and find it behaving in a certain manner? Or do you want to invoke the dialer from within your app?

Comment: are you talking about in-built dialer app ?

Comment: @Vikram , the user open my app , set the data, and when open the dialer, it behaves in a certain manner

Comment: @YugandharBabu ,I dont want to build a dialer app , i want to use the default key board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that the dialer is back by a ContentProvider. If this is the case and the ContentProvider is accessible, you can try modifying the contents exposed by the ContentProvider.

You can start with looking into the code of the Dialer application on github.